# Polars Join cleverly infer appropriate dtypes of join key?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

In `pl.join()`, Is there any syntax sugar to "cleverly" cast the dtype of join cols. e.g. the higher granularity option or just take the dtypes from df1? could we add it as optional param to `pl.join()`?

e.g. int32 -> int64, datetime[ms] -> datetime[ns]

to avoid the dreaded:
`exceptions.ComputeError: datatypes of join keys don't match`

Comment: You could cast "manually" using df1's schema e.g. `on = "col1", "col2"; df1.join(on=on, other=df2.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(df2.schema[col]) for col in on)` - not sure if there is any syntax sugar for it.

Comment: This has been discussed on the Polars issue tracker before, and the stance is that there will not be automatic upcasting. See for example https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own then monkey patch it to `pl.DataFrame`

This is only handles floats and ints but you can build off of it and improve it. It has ample room for improvement

```
def myjoin(self, 
        other: pl.DataFrame, 
        on: str | pl.Expr | None = None, 
        how: pl.type_aliases.JoinStrategy = 'inner', 
        left_on: str | pl.Expr | None = None, 
        right_on: str | pl.Expr | None = None, 
        suffix: str = '_right'):
    if left_on is None and right_on is None and on is not None:
        left_on=on
        right_on=on
    elif on is None and left_on is not None and right_on is not None:
        pass
        #should check for other consistency (len etc)
    else:
        raise ValueError("inconsistent right_on, left_on, on")
    if isinstance(left_on, str):
        left_on=[left_on]
    if isinstance(right_on, str):
        right_on=[right_on]
    for i, col in enumerate(left_on):
        if self.schema[col]!=other.schema[col]:
            if self.schema[col] in pl.datatypes.INTEGER_DTYPES and other.schema[col] in pl.datatypes.INTEGER_DTYPES:
                self=self.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Int64()))
                other=other.with_columns(pl.col(right_on[i]).cast(pl.Int64()))
            elif self.schema[col] in pl.datatypes.FLOAT_DTYPES and other.schema[col] in pl.datatypes.FLOAT_DTYPES:
                self=self.with_columns(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Float64()))
                other=other.with_columns(pl.col(right_on[i]).cast(pl.Float64()))
            else:
                raise ValueError("only floats and ints are upgraded, need to add TEMPORAL and other logic")
    return self.join(other, left_on=left_on, right_on=right_on, suffix=suffix, how=how)
pl.DataFrame.myjoin=myjoin
```

Then, if you have

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4]}).with_columns(a=pl.col('a').cast(pl.Int8()))
df2=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'c':[3,4,5]}).with_columns(a=pl.col('a').cast(pl.Int16()))
```

You can do

```
df.myjoin(df2, on='a')

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I only made it check for Floats and Ints and it just goes straight to the 64bit variety rather than trying to determine which one of the two needs casting and only casting that one. It also doesn't cast Ints to Floats but you could add that logic. It's probably better to make each of `self` and `other` lazy before the for loop that casts the join columns.  I also didn't attempt the datetime conversions but it should just be tedium to add it at this point.